# CSV into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I'm trying to load a CSV file into a single dimentional array. I can output the contents of the CSV file, but in trying to copy it into an array I'm having a bit of trouble.

Here is my existing code, which I realise is probably pretty bad but I'm teaching myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024
#define MAX_CSV_ELEMENTS 1000000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
    int varCount = 0;
    char CSVArray[MAX_CSV_ELEMENTS] = {0};

    FILE *csvFile = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    if (csvFile)
    {
        char *token = 0;
        while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, csvFile)) 
        {
            token = strtok(&line[0], ",");
            while (token)
            {
                varCount++;
                CSVArray[varCount] = *token; //This is where it all goes wrong
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
        }
        fclose(csvFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way I should be doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*token` means dereferencing the pointer `token` which is the address of the first character in a string that `strtok` found. That's why your code fills `CSVArray` with just the first characters of each token.

You should rather have an array of char pointers to point at the tokens, like:

```
char *CSVArray[MAX_CSV_ELEMENTS] = {NULL};
```

And then assign a pointer to its elements:

```
CSVArray[varCount] = token;
```

Alternatively, you can copy the whole token each time:

```
CVSArray[varCount] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
strcpy(CVSArray[varCount], token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the problem line. It is because you are assigning a pointer, not copying the text.

Try here http://boredzo.org/pointers/ for a tutorial on pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to put the `char *` that comes back from `strtok` into the `char` array.

I think you want to declare `CSVArray` as:

```
char * CSVArray[MAX_CSV_ELEMENTS] = {0};
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to do that; he needs to copy the text into the array, not point into the line buffer, which gets overwritten on the following read.

Comment: You could be right @Brian; I thought that too originally, but if you see that his CSVArray is initialized to the max number of csv *elements*, you could interpret that to mean he intends each slot in the array to be a `char *` to the tokenized string.  This would make more sense to me, since copying an already tokenized string would seem wasteful?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't want to be too critical of a learner, but it is rather hard to tell what was intended.