# Converting floating point csv to 2d array in c

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I need to convert a floating point csv to a 2D array in c. Have already saw an article ([Import CSV elements into a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266286/import-csv-elements-into-a-2d-array-in-c/24266565#24266565?newreg=0ccaa1c1b3ea4c1482255898ab2882c8)) which explains the conversion to an integer array.Can any one help in modifying this code or a new approach that i could use to convert the csv to a floating point 2D array
for eg: my csv contains values like 0.018869,0.015863,0.044758,0.027318,0.049394,0.040823,..... and is a 4400*500 values csv. so i would need to use a big array of size 4400*500 to include all of these values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the code that you have to try and solve the problem so that we can help you fix it. It's OK to edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use atof() to convert strings to floats.
[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm) is a link if you want to read up on it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//counters
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

char c = 0; //for storing a char at a time

char result_char_array[4] = {0}; //float is a 32 bit number, so 4 bytes

FILE *filep; //pointer to file structure

float results[100] = {0}; //to store the float

int main(void)
{

    filep = fopen("C:/Documents/test.csv", "r");      //open file , read only
    if (!filep)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n");
        return -1; //return negative number so you know something went wrong
    }

    c = fgetc(filep); //get first character

    while(c != EOF)
    {
        if((c == ',') || (c == '\n')) //we want to stop at each comma or newline
        {
            //i = 0; //reset the count
            results[j] = atof(result_char_array); //this converts a string to a float
            j++; //increment j
            memset(&result_char_array, 0, sizeof(result_char_array)); //clear the array
        }
        else
        {
            strncat(&result_char_array, &c, 1);
        }


        c = fgetc(filep); //get next character
        i++;
    }

    results[j] = atof(result_char_array); //convert last number

    fclose (filep); //always close the file

    for(k = 0; k <= j; k++)
    {
        printf("Number %d is: %f\n",k, results[k]); //loop through the results and print line by line
    }
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: haha ignore that commented out i = 0, I was playing around with how format it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [libcsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/), which is a CSV library written in ANSI C89. But be careful, libcsv is licensed under LGPL.